# Is it possible to see command history when telnetting into Microsoft Telnet Server?

Tags: windows, telnet

I'm in the unfortunate position of having to use telnet (windows client -> windows server). Does anyone know if there's a way to see command history (i.e., getting the up arrow and down arrow to recreate previous commands) whilst telnetting? BTW, I know about the standard command history settings for cmd.exe, which have no effect on the telnet session.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`doskey/history`** to list previous commands.

Comment: (And consider having something like WinSSHD installed; it even provides a much better terminal emulation.)

Comment: I'd forgotten all about doskey! After calling it with the /listsize=n arg I've got just about what I need. Thanks!